# Register remote machine as node is giving connection timed out on Grid Console

Tags: java, linux, selenium, selenium-grid

I have a hub set up on a physical Windows machine. I am trying to setup a node to connect to this hub on a headless Linux Red Hat VM.

I use this command to launch the node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role 
node -hub http://<IP>:5786/grid/register
```

This node registers successfully in the terminal with the following stacktrace

```
10:38:55.935 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision:  
'unknown'
10:38:55.936 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
2017-07-11 10:38:56.716:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1140ms to 
org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
10:38:56.800 INFO - Driver provider 
org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, 
browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match 
the current platform LINUX
10:38:56.800 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver 
registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, 
platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
10:38:56.800 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
10:38:56.800 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver 
registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
10:38:56.800 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
10:38:56.800 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not 
registered
10:38:56.801 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver 
registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, 
platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
2017-07-11 10:38:56.860:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
2017-07-11 10:38:56.905:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started 
o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@96def03{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-11 10:38:56.922:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started 
ServerConnector@69b2283a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:5555}
2017-07-11 10:38:56.923:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1346ms
10:38:56.923 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
10:38:56.967 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register 
every 
5000 ms.
10:38:56.968 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: 
http://<IP>/grid/register
10:38:57.322 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

When I go onto the console however, the following message is given:

```
DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to <IP>:5555 [/<IP>] failed: connect timed out
```

In addition, in my hub terminal the following messages occur:

```
11:00:26.189 INFO - Unregistering the node http://<IP of NODE>:5555 because 
it's been down for 60006 milliseconds
11:00:33.615 WARN - Cleaning up stale test sessions on the unregistered node 
http://<IP of NODE>:5555
```

This will just loop over and over.

I have looked into this a lot and have not been able to find anything helpful.

The closest thing I found was using a bridge connection instead of a NAT connection but I am under a corporate setting and cannot fiddle with any of these settings.

**EDIT**

```
08:53:22.664 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 
'unknown'
08:53:22.665 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
2017-07-12 08:53:23.505:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1194ms to 
org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
08:53:23.590 INFO - Driver provider 
org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, 
browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match 
the current platform LINUX
08:53:23.591 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver 
registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, 
version=, platform=WINDOWS}] does not match the current platform LINUX
08:53:23.591 INFO - Driver class not found: 
com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
08:53:23.591 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver 
registration is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
08:53:23.591 INFO - Driver class not found: 
com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
08:53:23.591 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not 
registered
08:53:23.592 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver 
registration is skipped:
registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, 
platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform LINUX
2017-07-12 08:53:23.650:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
2017-07-12 08:53:23.699:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started 
o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@363ee3a2{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-12 08:53:23.715:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started 
ServerConnector@cd3fee8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8151}
2017-07-12 08:53:23.715:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1404ms
08:53:23.724 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
08:53:23.765 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register 
every 5000 ms.
08:53:23.765 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: 
http://10.56.130.102:5786/grid/register
08:53:24.114 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

Comment: Please check your node port 5555 is allowed in the firewall for TCP and UDP connection

Comment: Thanks for the response, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: From hub machine, ping the node with the port. If you are getting ping response then firewall is allowed otherwise you need to allow the port in the firewall. In Windows, you can enable by  policy rule. In Linux some command are there to allow ports but I am not sure.

Comment: I can ping the machine, but I cannot ping the port. This means that I must allow the port on the node machine or the hub machine?

Comment: Port 5555 should be allowed in the node

Comment: hmm, i am using cryping to ping the specific port but it says that it cannot connect to it

Comment: That may be the issue. Please enable port using iptables. Open flle /etc/sysconfig/iptables: # vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables Append rule as follows: -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5555 -j ACCEPT Save and close the file. Restart iptables: # /etc/init.d/iptables restart

Comment: the last part gives me an error. It says failed to restart iptables.service: Unit is masked.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the outbound connections from your Windows machine on port `5555` which is the default port on which the node runs, is being blocked by your firewall in your Windows machine. Please see if [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717286(v=ws.11).aspx) link helps you open up the port on windows.

This also explains why the registration from the node to the hub is successful, but then the Hub marks the node as down/stale and later removes it because it cannot establish `HTTP GET` to the status URL that the node exposes.

Since usually port `8080` is always opened on machines, you can try running your `node` on this port, so that the hub can ping back the node for the status queries.

Pinging a machine and then triggering a http operation such as `HTTP GET` don't seem to be the same thing. See [this](https://serverfault.com/a/282710) for more information.

Comment: Hey, I will give this a shot! Thanks. I tried running it on port 8080 but it is giving me the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

It's quite clear from the error logs `DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to <IP>:5555 [/<IP>] failed: connect timed out` that the default port 5555 on which **`Selenium Grid Node`** listens is in use by some other application. So you can consider using some other port for **`Selenium Grid Node`** as follows:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -port 8143 -hub http://localhost:5786/grid/register
```

You can confirm the registration of the Selenium Grid Node through the following logs:

```
11:04:40.636 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
11:04:40.714 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
11:04:40.714 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:5786/grid/register
11:04:40.917 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

Next you can access the Selenium Grid Server console through **http://localhost:5786/grid/console** and confirm the node.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: I tried this, it still gives me the same error, it gives me the correct registration logs in the terminal but when I go to the console, that is where the error is.

Comment: Can you put the error stack trace in the Question area please? Thanks

Comment: See this `INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use` Seems no error. Thanks

Comment: Clear the cache and restart your machine. I think that will be enough. Thanks

Comment: Yes, on the grid console however it gives me 
DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to <IP>:8151 [/<IP>] failed: connect timed out

Comment: Okay, I will try that